# in one of -- in cloudera

Tags: sql, cloudera

I would like to create a conditional clause in Cloudera along the lines: 
In one of ... how can I do that ?

```
from old
where org_zone_name = in ('Specialist ' OR
'Vet'OR
'Surgeon' OR
'Nurse' OR
'Other')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want `in`?

```
where org_zone_name in ('Specialist', 'Vet', 'Surgeon', 'Nurse', 'Other')
```